# Wordpress isn't reflecting changes I make to a specific file via FTP

Tags: wp-admin, search, ftp

*Hello, I'm new to Wordpress so please let me know if there's any vital information I've left out.*

I've just migrated from my localhost to online: there were a few bumps but after fixing some paths everything seems to be working fine. Except for the search results page (and I think I know why).

I wanted more search results to show up, so in `Settings > Reading` I updated the number of posts to display on one page. However, now when I update `search.php`, the changes aren't reflected on the live site. My uninformed theory is that because I changed a setting via the wp-admin panel it somehow cached a current version of my `search.php` and is using that instead of the file I'm updating and reuploading.

I know this is probably incorrect, but I have no idea why changes I make to the file aren't being reflected. It is the only page I'm having this issue with, changes I make to other files are displayed instantly.

**UPDATE:** It seems like Wordpress creates a temporary file when you search for something with the slug `/?s=searchterm`: so I'm guessing that whatever creates that file is referencing an old version of `search.php` — if I'm correct, how do I fix this?

Comment: the problem can have a lot of causes (e.g. a plugin) and the most of the time, I see such problems which bad written themes. the theme may cache the result or just doesn't react to the setting or use another setting in "appearance" -> "customise".

Comment: WP itself doesn't do page caching, plugins are required for that

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is creating a cached version and serving as a static page.
Try disabling all caching plugins and try again.

Here are some examples of plugins to look out for: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/search/caching/

Once you have finished updates to your file then you can re-activate, or alternatively manually delete the cache in the plugin settings.